# Posting JSON and python Flask - any techniques to use the Werkzeug debugger?

Tags: python, debugging, flask, werkzeug

Alright, I'm working with a RESTful backend on my project, and submitting data via jquery.

I must say the werkzeug debugger is excellent for debugging specially when you're a terrible python programmer as me. You throw an exception on purpose where you want to investigate, and inspect the code and variables using the html the debugger rendered.

However when you send a post request instead of a get, if you throw an exception on the backend code, of course, the browser won't render the response text.

Is there any technique I can use to render the response text, considering it has javascript and everything?

I'm trying different things such as trying to inject the response text into a popup window, like:

```
           $.postJSON = function(url, data, callback, error_callback) {
                return jQuery.ajax({
                    'type': 'POST',
                    'url': url,
                    'contentType': 'application/json',
                    'data': JSON.stringify(data),
                    'dataType': 'json',
                    'success': callback,
                    'error': error_callback
                });
            };

            $.postJSON('/the_uri', {'foo': 'bar'}, 
            function(response) {
                var a = 0;
            }, 
            function(response) {
                var html = response.responseText;
                var my_window = window.open('', 'mywindow1', 'width=350,height=150');
                $(my_window.document).find('html').html(html);
            });
        });
```

But this won't take care of the javascript very well.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: any chance you have a solution yet?  I *really* wish I could do this.

Comment: No solution yet, sorry... I'm not looking for one anymore, what you may want to do is to attach a debugger to your flask application on the server and step through/trace your code there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach was nearly correct. I am using the following code to open the response text in a new window (not specific to Werkzeug or Flask at all):

```
var w = window.open('', 'debug_stuff', 'width=540,height=150');
w.document.open();
w.document.write(response.responseText);
w.document.close();
```

The last line is the most important. Without it, the code would behave as yours -- it would not execute any JavaScript, because the browser doesn't know the DOM has been fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Not javascript, but have you tried to use Firebug, you can use the option for viewing the response in a new tab (Open Response in New Tab).

Answer (score 0):

If you're ready to make some changes on both the client and the server code, you can try this. In your error callback you would re-send the JSON data but as a synchonous form submission. You would create the form using jQuery, give it an `input` tag and put your JSON in that and submit the form. Something like:

```
$('<form method="post" style="display:none;">')
    .attr('action', 'xxx')
    .append(
        $('<input>').val(JSON.stringify(data))
    ).appendTo('body')
    .submit();
```

On the server-side, you would have to accept JSON the regular way when the request's content type is application/json and as form data, eg:

```
json_string = request.form.get('__json')
if json_string:
    data = json.loads(json_string)
```

I have never tried this but I know the problem you're having and it can waste a lot of time. If you try it I'd like to know how it works out.

Comment: I guess I still want to spend some thinking on this but never really found enough time. I did play around with this solution a few months back, and it didn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

Markus' answer works perfectly. thanks so much! this saved me so much hassle.

also consider assigning your handlers to a jqxhr object

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#jqxhr-object

```
var jqxhr = $.post(...)
```

then you would write to your new window

```
w.document.write(jqxhr.responseText);
```